# Is Cea's lemma sharp?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, bilinear-form, finite-element-method

Given a problem in weak formulation
$$ \begin{align}
\text{find $u\in V$ s.th. for all $v\in V$} \\
a(u,v) = f(v)
\end{align}
$$

with bilinear form $a:V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, bounded with constant $k$ 
$$ a(u,v) \le k\|u\| \|v\|\quad \forall u,v\in V
$$
and elliptic with constant $c$ 
$$ a(u,u) \ge c \|u\|^2\quad \forall u\in V
$$ 
Denote by $u$ the solution to the weak problem in $V$ and by $u_m$ the solution to the same problem restricted to the $V_m$ of a Galerkin scheme for $V$, then Cea's lemma states that there holds a quasi-best approximation property
$$ \|u-u_m\| \le \frac{k}{c} \inf_{v\in V_m} \|u-v\| \,.
$$
For symmetric $a(u, v) = a(v, u)$ the coefficient can be improved to $\sqrt{\frac{k}{c}}$.

> My question is now the following: Is this bound sharp? Ie. are there examples where equality holds? If not, are there any lower bounds known?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the proof. If there is equality in the hypothesis ($a(x,y) = c\times x\cdot y$) then there is equality also in the Cea's lemma.

Comment: There are two inequalities in the proof that would both need to be equatlities - and not for arbitrary elements, but for the solution of the galerkin equation (ie. the solution of the weak problem restricted to $V_m$) and the best-approximation (ie. the infimum in the equation - is that even a real minimum?). Right now I don't see how I would construct a sharp example, even while looking at the proof. Maybe you could elaborate your answer a bit should you have a more concrete idea how to do this.

Comment: there is the case in which both inequalities are the same.